# how to redirect a page to external url in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `$location.path('www.google.com');` to open an external link , but the URL is not overridden so it is taking me to the URL defined as otherwise in `app.js`

I also used `$window.open` but it didn't do anything.

How can I open an external link, preferably in a new tab?

```
myApp.service('GetUrl', ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {
    this.ToUrl = function(file, url){
        $http.post('/geturl')
        .success(function(respond){
            //I'm getting respond as https://demo.docusign.net/
            window.open(respond); //this is were I have performed redirection here server sends the response but window.open or $window.open is not performing anything it just stays in the same page
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: use `window.open("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using? Using `window.open()` does work but if it doesn't work in your app then we would need to see that code to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was firefox preventing redirection than angular. Thanks for help.